# Detecting if the file from youtube is stream live

Tags: php

I want to detect if a given file on YouTube is broadcasted live. I have not found any information on this subject in the youtube api documentation. Is it possible at all?

Comment: Vote to close as too broad

Comment: I do not understand?

Comment: And neither do we. That's the problem.

Comment: I want to detect if a given file on YouTube is broadcasted live.